# How to change default server port using spring mvc and maven

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat

I have a project with spring web mvc 5.2 and maven and I want to set server port in my properties file how can I do this like spring boot

Comment: You cannot unless you are also using an embedded container. However for an application deployed on a servlet container/app server this simply isn't possible (for Spring Boot it isn't either).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how can I do this on Tomcat? Is there any way to set whitch port I want to deploy a specific war file?

Comment: You need to create an additional connector and configure your application to use it. You do this all in the tomcat server.xml.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do this?

Comment: I strongly suggest a read of the tomcat documentation.

Comment: Ok, sure  I'm new in Tomcat. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In pom.xml you can add this plugin(i am using tomcat 7), by using the port tag in configuration tag we can change the default port number.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <port>9091</port>              
          <path>/</path>                
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How can I find compatible plugin with my tomcat and if My tomcat in local be diffrent from Tomcat on server is this working too?

Comment: This won't work with a remote tomcat, only if you use maven to run tomcat.